# Ethernet 10/100 Mbps

Tags: macos, mac, network, ethernet

I have recently upgraded my Internet access to 100Mbps upload / 30Mbps download, upgraded also the modem router and switches to 100Mbps.
Tested with Speediest app (Mac OSX) and found these figures:
- download 94 Mbps (excellent)
- upload 14 Mbps

The upload speed should be somehow around 30Mbps. What is wrong?
My laptop is indeed capable of delivering 30Mbps up, maybe it's because of old Ethernet cables? What should I check?

Thanks

Comment: If it can pull 100 one way, it's not the cabling. Test again at different times of day; most of these services have an "up to" clause in them & make no guarantees of actual obtainable speed.

Comment: Thanks Tetsujin, I was thinking the same. As a matter of fact, the same situation is reproduces on other computers on the same network. Seems like the max upload is 15 Mbps, not 30 as advertised !